# Support compression in .NET OData 4 Client

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services, asp.net-web-api, astoria, wcf-data-services-client

### Problem

I have added support for http compression in our self-hosted OWIN/Katana Web API OData 4 service but I do not see how to support compression in the .NET client.  I'm using OData libraries v6.5.0 and I need to support compression/decompression in the client ([OData v4 Client Code Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b786c0e-79d1-4a50-89a5-125e57475937)).  I am using Deflate encoding for the compression via an ActionFilter.  Everything compresses correctly on the server as confirmed via Fiddler but I do not know how to configure the client to support this now that the OData client uses the Request and Response Pipelines instead of the now defunct [WritingRequest and RecievingResponse events that once supported this very scenario](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2011/10/04/odata-compression-in-windows-phone-7-5-mango.aspx).

### Attempts

By experimentation I found that I can hook into the `ReceivingResponse` event on my `DataServiceContext` and then call ReceivingResponseEventArgs.ResponseMessage.GetStream() but I don't know what to do to overwrite the message content correctly.  If I CopyTo() on the stream, I get a null reference exception at Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataMessageReader.DetectPayloadKind().  I presume this is because the stream was read to the end and the position needs to be set back to zero but I cannot do that because the stream also throws an exception when setting the position back because it says it does not support seeking.  I presume this is simply due to the stream being read-only.  Even if I could copy the stream to decompress it successfully, how do I modify the response message content with the decompressed content?  I don't see any hooks for this at all in the RequestPipeline or ResponsePipeline.  To clarify, I want to decompress the response message content and then set it for the materialization that occurs soon after, how might I do that?  Extra credit for how to also send compressed requests to the OData service. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OData client use the HTTPWebRequest and HTTPWebReponse, which supports the compression well. Try setting the AutomaticDecompression of HTTPWebRequest to Deflate or GZip, in SendingRequest2 pipeline event, like this:

```
private void OnSendingRequest_(object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs args)
{
    if (!args.IsBatchPart) // The request message is not HttpWebRequestMessage in batch part.
    {
        HTTPWebRequest request = ((HttpWebRequestMessage)args.RequestMessage).HttpWebRequest;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    } 
}
```

Then in response, HTTPWebResponse will decompress the stream automatically, before the materialization work.